# How to write a double loop with two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list (`pd.daraframe rec`) of rectangles described by coordinates of two points `[(top_right_x, top_right_y), (bottom_left_x, bottom_left_y)]` and a list (`pd.dataframe points`) of points (x, y).

For each rectangle I need to find the shortest distance to any of the point (the closest point). I wrote a function that calculates the distance between a rec and a point. How to calculate that?

```
distant_function(top_right_x, top_right_y, bottom_left_x, bottom_left_y, x, y)
```

I need to apply that function to every row in rec frame (first four args fixed) and inside that loop apply to every row in points frame (last two args changing) and then get min.

I guess I need apply, lambda and map, but cannot get the right code.

```
for row in rec.iterrows: 
    rec['min_distance'] = min(map(distant_function(points['x'], points['y'], row['top_right_x'], row['top_right_y'], row['bottom_left_x'], row['bottom_left_y'], points))
```

Comment: Please show us the code you already tried :) You can also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57277290/looping-through-two-separate-dataframes-haversine-function-store-the-values

Comment: for row in rec.iterrows:
 rec['min_distance'] = min(map(distant_function(points['x'], points['y'], row['top_right_x'], row['top_right_y'], row['bottom_left_x'], row['bottom_left_y'], points))

Comment: I got an error like "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous"

Comment: I don't think you are applying well the `map` function...